# matplotlib xticks not being assigned for 0

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am writing a code in python to map 30 values to a list of `(0,1,2,.......29)` using `matplotlib`.

Later i want to use `xticks` to give specific names for the x axis values from 0 to 29.
However when i use the `matplotlib.pyplot.xticks` method,my origin is left as it was and the name I assigned for 0 appears in place of 1 and so on until 29th item in the list. And after that for the 30th item,(i.e the name to be assigned for 29) appears at the end with no point corresponding to it.

Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: Are you trying to change the tick values or labels? If labels you want to use `xticklabels`, not `xticks`

Comment: Don't use `xticklabels` as it is dangerous.  The labels will be un-connected to the data.

Comment: @tcaswell My bad, just checked the docs. I didn't realise `xticks` could set the labels too

Comment: Thank you guys for all the help. I figured out my mistake.

Comment: Please write an answer to your own question

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with the `set_xticklabels` method for `axis` objects, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(10)
y = range(10)
labels = ['super long axis label' for i in range(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.plot(x, y)

# set custom tick labels
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

plt.show()
```

[image]